# Advanced query using Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees 
(
    EmployeeID      int         IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,EmployeeNumber int         UNIQUE
    ,DateOfBirth    datetime        NOT NULL
    ,FirstName      nvarchar(14)    NOT NULL
    ,MiddleName     nvarchar(14)    NOT NULL
    ,LastName       nvarchar(16)    NOT NULL
    ,DateHired      datetime        NOT NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE Customers 
(
    CustomerID      int         IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,FirstName      nvarchar(14)    NOT NULL
    ,MiddleName     nvarchar(14)    NOT NULL
    ,LastName       nvarchar(16)    NOT NULL
    ,DateLastVisited datetime       NOT NULL 
    ,EmailAddress   nvarchar(52)    NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Departments 
(
    DepartmentID    int         IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,Code           nchar(4)        UNIQUE
    ,Name           nvarchar(40)    NOT NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE DepartmentEmployees 
(
    DepartmentEmployeeID    int     IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,EmployeeID     int             NOT NULL
            CONSTRAINT Department_Employee REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeID)
    ,DepartmentID   int         NOT NULL
            CONSTRAINT Employee_Department REFERENCES Departments(DepartmentID)
    ,DateStarted    datetime        NOT NULL
    ,DateEnded      datetime        NOT NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE Salaries 
(
    SalaryID        int         IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,EmployeeID     int         NOT NULL
            CONSTRAINT Salaried_Employee REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeID)
    ,Amount     money           NOT NULL
    ,DateStarts     datetime        NOT NULL
    ,DateEnds       datetime        NOT NULL 
)
```

I have inserted a data according to the table requirement.

I am working on this question: *Get all employees first and last name, with a department code and a salary*

I have written this query for the question but it is not working.

```
SELECT  
    E.FirstName, E.LastName, D.Code, S.Amount 
FROM
    Employees E
INNER JOIN
    Salaries S ON E.EmployeeID = S.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN
    Departments D ON D.DepartmentID = E.EmployeeID
```

Please help me out

Comment: There's no direct connection between employees and departments, you need to join Employees - DepartmentEmployees - Departments

Comment: When you say it's not working it's helpful to explain why. Not working could mean a number of things; an error, unexpected results, no results, causes your pc to catch fire (the last one is a jest, but you get the idea). Help us help you by explaining what's happening and what you expect to happen.

Comment: @jenna your join is incorrect. Check `DepartmentEmployees` table, maybe it will help you figure out the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  E.FirstName,E.LastName, D.Code,S.Amount From Employees E
Inner Join Salaries S
On E.EmployeeID= S.EmployeeID
Inner join Departments D
**on D.DepartmentID= E.EmployeeID**
```

Are you sure you want to join with departmentID to EmployeeID?

Comment: You should ask questions in the question comments.

Comment: Yep.. It looks like I need to earn more reputation to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you all you need

```
select  firstname, lastname ,Departments.Code as DepartmentCode,Salaries.Amount  as Salary
from 
Employees 
inner join DepartmentEmployees on Employees.EmployeeID = DepartmentEmployees.EmployeeID  
inner join Departments on   DepartmentEmployees.DepartmentID   = Departments.DepartmentID  
inner join Salaries on Employees.EmployeeID = Salaries.EmployeeID
```

Every Employee belongs to a department( DepartmentEmployees). Because of that you must join Employee with DepartmentEmployees. In next join you can find the code of Department and in 3rd join you find the salary amount from Salaries table.